# Sorting Java TreeMap by value not working when more than two values have the same sort-property

Tags: java, sorting, treemap

I want to sort a Java TreeMap based on some attribute of value. To be specific, I want to sort a `TreeMap<Integer, Hashset<Integer>>` based on the size of `Hashset<Integer>`. To achieve this, I have done the following:

**A Comparator class:**

```
private static class ValueComparer implements Comparator<Integer> {
    private Map<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>  map = null;
    public ValueComparer (Map<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> map){
        super();
        this.map = map;
    }

@Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        HashSet<Integer> h1 = map.get(o1);
        HashSet<Integer> h2 = map.get(o2);

        int compare = h2.size().compareTo(h1.size());

        if (compare == 0 && o1!=o2){
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return compare;
        }
    }
}
```

**A usage example:**

```
TreeMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> originalMap = new TreeMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>();

//load keys and values into map

ValueComparer comp = new ValueComparer(originalMap);
TreeMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>(comp);
sortedMap.putAll(originalMap);
```

**The problem:**

This doesn't work when `originalMap` contains more than 2 values of the same size. For other cases, it works alright. When more than two values in the map are of same size, the third value in the new sorted-map is null and throws NullPointerException when I try to access it.

I can't figure out what the problem is. Woule be nice if someone could point out.

**Update:**
Here's an example that works when two values have the same size: http://ideone.com/iFD9c
In the above example, if you uncomment lines 52-54, this code will fail- that's what my problem is.

Comment: We need to know what you expect when 2 or more values have the same size (which, as I understand, is used as the key in the new map).  Are you aware of the properties of a Map, i.e. that the keys need to be unique?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of it. Nothing is done to the keys- they remain unique and the above works perfectly when less than 3 values have the same size. I do not have any preference with the sort order for multiple values with the same size- but they could as well be sorted by the key instead.

Comment: I am afraid you don't know what is going on here - the term "sorted map" is not properly defined. A map is a data structure to store  key/value pairs (where the key is unique) and to lookup values fast. You're not supposed to know anything about implementation details, therefore you cannot even say what the difference between a map and a sorted map should be. What can you do with a sorted map that you can't do with an unsorted one?

Comment: I edited the question replacing SortedMap with TreeMap. Does that solve it now? An unsorted stores its members in no particular order while a sortedmap stores them in some defined order- if I understand it correctly.

Comment: I'm afraid you do not - a Map alwasy stores its members in a particular order, namely in a order that allows fast inserts and lookups. If you need to sort data, use Lists or Arrays - a Map is not well suited for that (except that you may be able to get the values in key order).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: You cannot return `-1` from `ValueComparator` just because you want to avoid duplicate keys to not be removed. Check the contract of [`Comparator.compare`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29).

---

When you pass a `Comparator` to `TreeMap` you compute a ("new") place to put the entry. **No (computed) key can exist more than once in a `TreeMap`.**

---

If you want to sort the `orginalMap` by size of the value you can do as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    TreeMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> originalMap = 
        new TreeMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>();

    originalMap.put(0, new HashSet<Integer>() {{ add(6); add(7); }});
    originalMap.put(1, new HashSet<Integer>() {{ add(6); }});
    originalMap.put(2, new HashSet<Integer>() {{ add(9); add(8); }});


    ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>> list = 
        new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>>();
    list.addAll(originalMap.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer,HashSet<Integer>>>(){
        public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> o1,
                           Map.Entry<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> o2) {

            Integer size1 = (Integer) o1.getValue().size();
            Integer size2 = (Integer) o2.getValue().size();
            return size2.compareTo(size1);
        }
    });

    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton- your solution works great :) May I still ask why my method doesn't work (I'm interested to learn). If some change in my implementation would fix it, then it would be nice to use a Map instead of List to contain the sorted result.

Comment: I'm sorry, you cannot since the key in a `TreeMap` cannot exist more than once (in your case the key is the size of the value). When you put it a new value with the same size it will remove the old value. Updated answer slightly.

Comment: Ok, but why does it work when I have two values with the same size (both of them are inserted) and doesn't work when I have three values with the same size?

Comment: I think you are mistaken, a `TreeMap` cannot have duplicate keys, check this [ideone example](http://ideone.com/ypVZV).

Comment: Could you please have a look at my example here: http://ideone.com/iFD9c ? I've added this in the question too. IN the above code, if you uncomment lines 52-54, the program no longer works.

Comment: Ouch, returning `-1` from your `Comparator` to avoiding duplicate entries to be removed is not how the contract is for [`Comparator.compare`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) is specified. You just cannot do it like that! (updated answer)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I'm still not clear where is this mentioned in the documentation. Since I want to compare based on size of values, am I not free to choose a logic for comparison ?

Comment: From the api documentation: **The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y.** If you always return `-1` for equal sizes then you have broken this property.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparator doesn't respect the Comparator contract: if `compare(o1, o2) < 0`, then `compare(o2, o1)` should be `> 0`. You must find a deterministic way of comparing your elements when both sizes are the same and the integers are not identical. You could perhaps use the `System.identityHashCode()` of the integers to compare them in this case.

That said, I really wonder what you could do with such a map: you can't create new Integers and use them to get a value out of the map, and you can't modify the sets that it holds.

Side note: your comparator code sample uses `map` and `data` to refer to the same map.

Comment: I thought this is handling the case: "when both sizes are the same and the integers are not identical":

if (compare == 0 && o1!=o2){
            return -1;
        }

Yes, I'm aware of the drawbacks of this method and I will find better alternatives for my problems later. But I started with this, and would love to learn why this happens.

Thanks, edited to correct the mistake (data and map).

Comment: You handle the case, but you handle it by breaking the contract. Re-read my answer again: you're returning -1 when comparing i1 and i2, and you're also returning -1 when returning i2 and i1. This means that i1 is both < and > i2.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparator logic (which I'm not sure I follow why you'd return -1 if the set sizes are equal but they keys are different) shouldn't affect what the Map itself returns when you call `get(key)`.

Are you positive you aren't inserting null values into the initial map? What does this code look like?

Comment: If the sizes of values being compared are same, then the variable "compare" would equal zero - thus the new map would think the two keys are duplicates and only insert one of them. I don't want this, I want to retain ALL key-value pairs from the original map, so I can't return 0 from the comparator.

Yes, I am not inserting nulls in the initial map.

Comment: Here's how the code looks like: http://ideone.com/iFD9c (added this to question too).

Comment: That is going to lead to an unstable sort then, if you return -1 when A and B have the same size, and also -1 when B and A have the same size. I would rethink using a Comparator to do this sort of thing.

Comment: how'd you suggest me to do this then?

Answer (score 1):

You can have TreeMap ordered only by keys. There is no way of creating TreeMap ordered by values, because you will get StackOverflowException.

Think about it. To get an element from a tree, you need to perform comparisions, but to perform comparisions, you need to get elements.

You will have to sort it in other collection or to use Tree, you will have to encapsulate the integer (from entry value) also into the entry key and define comparator using that integer taken from a key.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot use a comparator that returns 0 with a Set, this might work: Add all the elements in `originalMap.entrySet()` to an `ArrayList` and then sort the `ArrayList` using your `ValueComparer`, changing it to `return 0` as necessary.

Then add all the entries in the sorted `ArrayList` to a `LinkedHashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem as the original poster. I had a TreeMap i wanted to sort on a value. But when I made a comparator that looked at the value, i had issues because of the breaking of the comparator that JB talked about. I was able to use my custom comparator and still observe the contract. When the valuse I was looking at were equal, i fell back to comparing the keys. I didn't care about the order if values were equal.

```
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
    if(base.get(a)[0] == base.get(b)[0]){ //need to handle when they are equal
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }else if (base.get(a)[0] < base.get(b)[0]) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    } // returning 0 would merge keys
```